# Cocoa : Notification if unmount request fails?

Tags: cocoa, notifications, mount

Is there a way to know is a unmounting request fails ? I'm calling `unmountAndEjectDeviceAtPath` it works well when the drive is not in use.

But when it's in use, nothing happens. I first thought NSWorkspaceWillUnmountNotification would be fired but no.

Any idea ?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were you checking the return value from `-unmountAndEjectDeviceAtPath:`?

Anyway, the docs for that point out that "[t]he `unmountAndEjectDeviceAtURL:error:` [method] is preferable as it will provide more detailed error information."  So, I recommend you use that.

Comment: Well I wasn't. And in fact, if it works it returns true, if not false. thx